# reading from an input file given by command line

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am relatively new to python but what my code is trying to accomplish to check if a graph is bipartite what I have here is my code and what my current problem is that i am having error is how I reading a text file given by user input and then putting it through the function i know i am accessing the file but then I had an error where it was not reading the lines properly. that was fixed  but now it is not being sent though the function. giving me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "color.py", line 4, in <module>

    class color():

  File "color.py", line 83, in color

    f = iscolor(f)

TypeError: iscolor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'src'
```

here below is my code

if you have any question feel free to state them I have tried other methods they are commented out along with the actual comments if  wish to see what i've done though it is a bit of a mess as some lines i took apart or reused to fix previous errors.

```
import sys 
import re

class color():



    def _init_(self , vertex):
        self.vertex = vvertex
        self.graph =  [0 for column in range(vertex)]
        self.graph =  [0 for row in range(vertex)]

    #if true if the Graph is bipartite
    # otherwise colorable

    def iscolor(self, src):


        #set color array to set -1as no color 
        clear[-1] * self.vertex


        #start coloring the first point
        clear[src] = 1

        #make a line of in and out
        queue = []

        queue.append[src]

        # run
        while queue:

            u = queue.pop()


        #return false if there is a self-loop

            if self.graph[u][u] == 1:
                return False;

            for vertex in range(self.vertex):

                # found an edge thats not colored
                if self.graph[u][vertex] == 1 and clear[vertex] == -1:

                    #put it in
                    clear[vertex] = 1 - clear[u]

                    queue.append(vertex)

                #found an edge its colored with the same color as befor
                elif self.graph[u][vertex] == 1 and clear[vertex] == clear[u]:

                    return False

        return True

        #open the file from input

        #with open(sys.argv[0]) as f:

    f = open(sys.argv[1])

    string = f.read()

    string = string.split(" ")

    #Grab the string individually then convert
    #int_list = [int(i) for i in f]

     #string = list(map(int, string))

    #f = iscolor(int_list, f)



#read the integers from the file

    for line in f:

        vertexstart = [int(x) for x in line.split()]    
    f = iscolor(f)



   #print("is two colorable") if f.iscolor(0) else print("is not two colorable")

  #print`enter code here`
  #print( " connected component(s)")
```

Comment: For starters, I think your indentation is off. Is `for line in f:` really supposed to be nested in the class?

Comment: that because of when i placed into the page to be posted it gave me an error and asked me to do a action where it "corrected" the indentations to be more visually correct i thought it would help let people read the code better.